# Configuring the powertools on a different port

Tags: 2013-sp1, powertools

I am trying to add the Powertools to a 2013-SP1 installation.

However the CME is running (for reasons outside of my control) under port 82. When looking at the [Powertool installation instructions](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-2011-power-tools/wiki/InstallationGuide) it does mention an option for a different port, but the instructions are for older code.

The result is that icons are missing, and all the powertool options are shown in the ribbon:
[image]
[image]

I have looked around in the powertool code, but can't find the code or configuration to fix this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: I think your link to the 'PowerTools installation instructions' is wrong. It would be good to know which ones you've followed, so can you correct the link? Did you use the installer? As far as I know, it works fine for a different port but I'll admit that I haven't tried that recently.

Comment: Hi @PeterKjaer, stupid copy/paste mistake. It was the  
tridion-2011-power-tools installation manual

Comment: Wow, those are really old indeed. Could you try using the installer instead? It's available at: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-59cCi_8LTZVE1sVlFOeFR4b2M